# Making printf do the right thing with floating point

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

I'm trying to make printf 'do the right thing' with floating point numbers, i.e.:

- Never lose information, always print as many decimals as are needed for the exact value
- Don't print a bunch of redundant trailing zeros
- Switch to scientific notation if the output would otherwise be unreasonably large

`%.20g` seems to do all that, but there's one more thing I would like to get:

- If the value is an integer, do print a trailing '.0' to indicate it is a floating point number with an integer value, not a number of type integer

Is there any way to get the fourth criterion without losing any of the first three?

Comment: Is this about the C printf ? If so, please consider adding the C tag, or the correspondent one

Comment: I don't think you can perfectly capture all 4 cases with printf alone. You could printf to a dummy variable and append the '.0' if it's missing a decimal point before pushing to the actual string.

Comment: @Pyrce that might be a solution, the problem is getting all the edge cases right, e.g. it would be wrong for large integers that print like 1e100; what other edge cases are there that I haven't thought of? - wait, maybe I could make the criterion be if the output contained only decimal digits and perhaps a leading minus sign. That would play it safe with the edge cases.

Comment: In my book, `%a` is the right thing for floating-point numbers.  To get what you want, you might just `sprintf` your number to a buffer and append a trailing "`.0`" if there isn't a dot already.

Comment: @rwallace I'd probably just append a '.0' if no '.' or 'e' characters are present in the original output as it's a bit simpler logic. You're potential outputs are limited by %f and %e so I don't think you'd have other edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the flag "#" will at least put a period at the end.  Try `%#.20g`.

The # flag is for example documented [here](http://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/%20here):
"Used with a, A, e, E, f, F, g or G it forces the written output to contain a decimal point even if no more digits follow. By default, if no digits follow, no decimal point is written."

Comment: Only gives the first half of his fourth criterion (missing the '0')

Comment: That does print a trailing decimal point, but it also goes back to printing a lot of redundant trailing zeros.

Comment: I see.  Maybe the easiest thing is, rather than using printf to fix this, to detect an integer yourself (searching for a period in the printf output), and just append `.0` by hand in that case.